# Can I cut off ONE phone jack, not the others?

Tags: telephone

I have a landline and want to keep it.  But I want to inactivate/close off one jack while keeping the others alive? Is that possible?

Comment: In what way do you want to "inactivate" or "close off" a jack? Do you simply want to make the hole in the wall disappear? Is it a flush mount jack as shown in [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/252843/34147), or is it a surface mount jack? More details a needed. Please [edit] to answer these questions and provide a picture of the jack in question.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the wiring scheme. While typical Ethernet twisted pair networking is always in a star configuration, ordinary voice phone service (POTS) can be in a star configuration (all jacks wired to a central location) *or* it can be in a daisy-chain configuration (central location to jack 1, jack 1 to jack 2, jack 2 to jack 3, etc.) or a mix.

Take a look at the jack you want to remove. If there is a single cable with 2 wires from the cable connected to the jack, you can safely cut it. If there are *two* cables, each with 2 wires connected to the jack then you can't cut it without affecting another jack elsewhere in your house.

Assuming this is a jack insert in a single-gang faceplate, like this (pictures from Amazon):

[image: jack inserted in faceplate]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

as opposed to an actual faceplate with integral jack, like this:

[image: faceplate with integral jack]

then I would pop the jack out of the faceplate *without* detaching or cutting any wires. Leave it in the box (if there is a box) or hanging inside the wall (if there is no box) and install a blank faceplate. You'll know it is there if you ever decide you want to use it again, but it won't be an attractive nuisance ("Hey, why doesn't this jack work?").

If your old jack was (a) screw connectors instead of punch down *and* (b) used as a splice between two cables, you can remove the wires from the screws, use IDC connects like [these from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3O3FDOu):

[image: Klein IDC]

to splice the wires, and then replace the jack/faceplate with a blank plate.

If the old jack is in a surface mount box then there is no "clean" replacement like a blank faceplate, so you can cut the wires but usually not remove the box cleanly without having to patch/paint.

Comment: Had to love the old phone wiring...

Comment: If it's the 2nd type of face plate, cut the wires as close to the attachment point as possible (removing the minimum amount of wire possible), then see if any other jacks no longer work. If there are one or more that don't, simply twist and (small) wire nut together all the wires in the wall, matching color to color.

Comment: @FreeMan.  Wire nutting phone wires together is not as reliable as using gel filled crimp splices, which seal out moisture and prevent corrosion.

Comment: I'm sure that's true, @PhilFreedenberg, but tell it to the hundreds/thousands/millions(?) of punch down blocks that have been in use throughout the US for at least 50 years (probably longer). If it's good enough for a company with 1000+ phones, a dry, unsealed connection is probably good enough for one splice in a residence.

Comment: @FreeMan Punch blocks are a different story. Not *sealed*. But extremely reliable. Wire nuts *at the tiny size* have usability issues. So the go to for splicing phone cables without a punch block or a usable screw terminal is the gel-filled IDC. Not because of the gel but because of the ease of using it properly and the reliability.

Comment: Fair enough, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact

Comment: THANKS -- this is all super helpful.  I did open the jack and see that there is only one cable, and it has two wires.  So does that mean I have a star-(rather than daisy-chain) configuration that allows me to cap them off and close off that jack, while still keeping the rest of my landline phone jacks working?  I'm nervous about losing my landline...

Comment: Correct. Or more technically, you either have a star configuration *or* this is the last in a chain. But either way, it should be safe to remove that jack.

Comment: You guys are SO helpful, thanks!  So to "cut" those wires, can I: 1) separate the wires from the jack; 2) remove the jack; and 3) put electric tape on the end and then just drywall over the hole where the jack was?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But unless there is some huge need to actually drywall over it, I highly recommend seeing if you can put a blank plate over the hole instead. That way if you ever want to use the jack again (or possibly even if you want to turn it into a network connection, depending on the type of cable), it will be much easier. But you *could* patch over it. Note that if you ever have electrical (e.g., 120V) then you can't just patch over it unless you disconnect the cable at the other end. But with phone (or network or coax for TV) you can drop the cable in the wall and patch over it.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I need to put a backsplash over that space, so I need the wall behind the backsplash to be flush/even.  That's why I am thinking of drywalling it.  And re my earlier question, I just put electric tape on the ends of the cable that I'm closing off, yes?

Comment: I mean the end (singular) of the cable I'm closing off.

Comment: Tape isn't technically required but is a good idea since the wires will be inaccessible.

Comment: You (and this site) are amazing. Neither my contractors, nor their electrician, nor the telephone guy who we had here knew what to do. They all said we'd almost for sure lose the line if we cut one jack.  I tried to figure out what "almost" meant and that's how I got to you. Thank you so much.

Comment: *Contractors* - wouldn't know unless they deal with wiring on a frequent basis. *Electrician* - some of them know, some don't, I trained my electrician years ago about network wires (similar to phone) because he could deal (better than I could) with fishing wires through walls but had no idea about the ends (like your situation), *telephone guy* - **absolutely should know**.